# How to add a border to a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uipickerview

How would you add a border to a UIPickerView? Cant seem to find any property for it. Is there some kind of work around?

I actually have two UIPickerViews next to each other, if possible I would like to get a thin white border around the both of them!

Answer (score 16):

As with any view, you can add a border by manipulating your `UIPickerView`'s layer property, ex:

```
// In Swift 3
picker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
picker.layer.borderWidth = 1

// In Swift
picker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
picker.layer.borderWidth = 1

// In Obj-C
picker.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
picker.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

Comment: Can I add a border only to a certain side?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the delegate method to apply styles and css on DatePicker ..
For example

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {


picker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
picker.layer.borderWidth = 1

return view 


}
```

This method will aplly all the properties on datepicker that is used in that particular view controller .